# how to install viber in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, viber

is it possible to install Viber VoIP client in Ubuntu ? So that I can call people from my Ubuntu system. I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
I followed these many steps :

Downloaded :

```
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip
```

Then unzipped it :

```
unzip Viber.zip
cd Viber
~/Viber/Viber.sh
```

But still it is not working. Giving error like "word unexpected" & "invalid encoding". If someone has installed, please suggest me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use wine to get the Viber working with wizard on ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install wine
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/windows/ViberSetup.exe
wine ViberSetup.exe
```

You can see the steps with screenshots on: http://www.unixmen.com/install-viber-in-linux-using-wine/

Comment: You don't need to do that. Viber has a linux version already.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you dont need to install viber through Wine anymore.
Viber now released Debian binary: www.viber.com/products/linux/‎

You must have 64bit version of Ubuntu, Debian, Mint or ZorinOS to be able to install this though.

Answer (score 1):

Installing `Viber` on Ubuntu:(without **wine**)

**For 64-bit Systems Only**:

Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> then run the following commands,

```
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/Viber.zip  
unzip Viber.zip   
cd Viber   
./Viber.sh
```

**In .deb method**

```
wget http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb  
sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo gdebi viber.deb
```

Or

```
wget -O viber64-NoobsLab.com.deb http://download.cdn.viber.com/cdn/desktop/Linux/viber.deb  
sudo dpkg -i viber64-NoobsLab.com.deb
```

**Direct download of .deb**

Download from [Viber.com](https://www.viber.com/en/products/linux)

`cd /viber_download_location/`

`sudo dpkg -i viber.deb`

**For 32-bit Systems**:

You can use `sudo dpkg --force-architecture -i viber.deb` command, but use of wine is advisable.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking, go to Viber's official page and download the latest version of the distro you are running. Currently, only Ubuntu and Fedora are supported.

[image: Link to the sccreenshot]

Installation can be easily completed through a Software installer or manually.